# How to sort Kotlin MutableList<Int>

Tags: java, sorting, kotlin

I am coming from a Java background, I have a simple array:

```
var statues: MutableList<Int> =  mutableListOf<Int>() 
statues.add(1)
statues.add(3)
statues.add(2)
var sortedArray: MutableList<Int> =  mutableListOf<Int>()
sortedArray = statues.sortedArray()
```

How do I sort this simple array and store in the variable sortedArray?

Comment: If you're using a [good IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), the auto-complete feature will give you suggestions for possible methods you can call on `statues`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you may like to know that you can write: var statues: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 3, 2)

Answer (score 5):

Since it's mutable data structure you can sort in place with [sort()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html)

> `fun <T : Comparable<T>> MutableList<T>.sort() (source)`
>
> Sorts elements in the list in-place according to their natural sort
>   order.

```
  val sortedArray = statues
  sortedArray.sort()
```

But I guess you probably intend to make a copy of the list since you are declaring two variables. In that case:

```
 val sortedArray = statues.sorted()
```

By the way that is a list, not an array.

A couple of tips: a rule of thumb in programming is favoring immutability, in this case using `val` instead of `var` if possible. Also you don't need to indicate the type twice in the declaration. This suffices:

```
val statues: MutableList<Int> =  mutableListOf()
```

Comment: everything correct - but `val sortedArray = statues.sorted()` is a lot more convenient than calling `.toMutableList().sort()`